# Confused about the method getTime and getTimeImpl in java.util.Date?

Tags: java, design-patterns, java.util.date

```
 public long getTime() {
    return getTimeImpl();
}

private final long getTimeImpl() {
    if (cdate != null && !cdate.isNormalized()) {
        normalize();
    }
    return fastTime;
}
```

I'm a little confused about the code segment.
Why didn't he write it like below?
I think it may have more readability.

```
public long getTime(){
        if (cdate != null && !cdate.isNormalized()) {
            normalize();
        }
        return fastTime;
    }
```

Comment: This to me doesn't seem like any pattern. It may just be the developer's way of doing things. One thing that comes to mind is that it could have been done for separating overridable method `getTime()` from business logic i.e. `getTimeImpl()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `Date.writeObject()` also calls `Date.getTimeImpl()`.

EDIT: Yes, `getTime()` just calls `getTimeImpl()`. I think `getTimeImpl()` is private implementation which can be changed in future, while `getTime()` is public API which cannot be changed.

Comment: Why can't writeObject() calls getTime ? I think getTimeImpl() is unnecessary.In additional, I know the nickname can be Chinese after seeing yours.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason is that you can extend the Date class and override the method getTime().

Comment: Except that you really can't because `getTimeImpl()` is also `private` so it's not visible to derived classes.